# [SerializationException: Typen System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat when trying to save Bitmap

Tags: c#, exception, serialization, bitmap

I'm running C# MVC 5. I'm using CEFsharp.offscreen to load a webbrowser. Everything works like a charm.

But when trying to save a screenshot I get this SerializationException, that:

> the type System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat is not marked as serializable.

I tried adding [Serializable] on top of all my classes. But to no avail.

My code looks like this:

**Controller**

```
   byte[] bytes = renderer.TakeScreenshot().ConvertToByteArray();
```

**Rendererer**

```
public Image TakeScreenshot()
    {
        try
        {
            return Task.Run(async () => { return await BrowserHolder.GetInstance().ScreenshotAsync(); }).Result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ;

           var x = e.InnerException;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**And the Helper class with extensions**

```
 public static byte[] ConvertToByteArray(this Image img)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, img);
            img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Code stops on

```
formatter.Serialize(stream, img);
```

Error in part Swedish.

> [SerializationException: Typen System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat i sammansättningen System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a är inte deklarerad som serialiserbar.]
>      System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format) +0
>      WebApplication.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in C:\Users\palss\Desktop\CefSharp.AppDomain-master källa\CefSharp.AppDomain-master\WebApplication\Controllers\HomeController.cs:28
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binary-serialization ,

Comment: have a look https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/1835 this might be helpful

Comment: What you doing does not make sense: you are trying to save same image twice in different formats in the same stream... And images are generally not "serializable", but support `Save` (and "load") by themselves... Removing `formatter.Serialize(stream, img);` is likely all you need for whatever you want to achieve.

Comment: 1) spinning up a task only to immediately call `Result` defeats the benefit of tasks.  2) `ScreenshotAsync` is already `async` so there is no need to use `Task.Run()` at all.  Just `await` it